# How to filter mlr3 task dataset by feature value

Tags: r, mlr3

I have a mlr3 task, where I have dataset like this:

Dataset "all"

```
all <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "b"),
              v2 = c(1, 2),
              data = c("test", "train"))

library(mlr3)
task <- TaskClassif$new("loan", all, target = "v1")
```

How could I filter task by column "data" value "train"?

I tried task$filter(data == "train") and a lot of other combinations, but don't work.

```
dput(task)
<environment>

str(task)
Classes 'TaskClassif', 'TaskSupervised', 'Task', 'R6' <TaskClassif:loan>
```

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of the example

Comment: @akrun, do you mean this (see in question)?

Comment: I guess it is in some environment.  Can you show the code to create this data so that it can be reproduced (along with the packages used)

Comment: @akrun, how about now?

Comment: Please check the solution below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `as.data.table` method

```
methods(class = 'Task')
#[1] as_task       as_tasks      as.data.table
```

So, we can convert it to a `data.table` and use the methods of data.table for subsetting

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(task)[data == 'train']
#   v1  data v2
#1:  b train  2
```

Or can extract the `data`

```
task$data()[data == 'test']
#    v1 data v2
#1:  a test  1
```

---

Or create a new instance

```
tasktrain <-  TaskClassif$new("loantrain",
           task$data()[data == 'train'], target = "v1")
tasktrain$data()
#   v1  data v2
#1:  b train  2
```

Comment: It returns class "data.table", but I want to keep task class.

Comment: For me last variant works, because it returns right dataset with right class. Thank you, @akrun.

Comment: If there is a method without creating new instance, then it would be better, but this solution works too.

Comment: @Jānis it is an R6 object

Comment: I am new with mlr3 and R6 and I don't know how it is important to save the same instance. If it is not important, then ok.

Comment: @Jānis Have you checked the `mlr3` [vignettes](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/train-predict.html). With `tsk`, they showed some examples to create train

Comment: Basically, it is the set up of learners that is crucial

Comment: thx. I will check mlr3 vignettes again. It looks like it will help me to understand more some things. This is last comment.

Comment: Usually there is no reason to change the task in place after creation. For viewing purposes, use `task$data()` or the data.table S3 method as shown by akrun. Also I suggest to read more on the structure of R6 objects to feel more confident in the long run.